# JavaScript: Get the value of a date input field using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of a date input field and alert it,but I always get an empty string or undefined. Any help on how to get the value of this field will be appreciated.

code -

```
var end = $('#datetimepicker2').val();

$('#sub').on('click', function () {
    alert(end);
});
```

**HTML CODE**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input-group-sm" placeholder="Enter Date" id="datetimepicker" aria-label="...">
```

I am using bootstrap-datepicker plugin to get the date.
EDIT: I want to get the date in yyyy/mm/dd format and store it in a variable

Comment: post the html code for the datepicker

Comment: when `var end`  line get executed?

Comment: @GabrielMesquita I just made the edit now

Comment: your id is datetimepicker and in jquery you have datetimepicker2, is that it?

Comment: @GabrielMesquita I have two input field for date. I copied the wrong one . But the code is correct.

Comment: I've tried to answer your problem below, give it a try and get back to me if it worked.

Comment: And what is #sub? You want to get the value after you click this #sub? if it is, your end var should be inside the click callback.

Comment: @GabrielMesquita #sub is a button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `var end = $('#datetimepicker2').val();` gets executed, the `<input id="datepicker2">` element has no value.

It remains empty because you have not defined an event handler to update it when the value has changed. The following should be a working example of what you are trying accomplish.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Date Time Picker:</strong></td>
        <td>
            <input id="datetimepicker2" class="datetimepicker" value=""/>
        <td>
        <td><button id="sub">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    // If the datepicker2 input is empty, this will be empty, even after you change it.
    var end = $('#datetimepicker2').val();
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();

    // This will update the "end" variable as it changes.
    $(document).on('change', '#datetimepicker2', function() {
        end = $(this).val();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#sub', function () {
        alert(end);
    });
</script>
```

***ps***: *I changed the* `$(x).on(event,function)` *to* `$(document).on(event,element,function)` *because I've had better results with this as the DOM is manipulated over time.*

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: I am glad that I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#datePicker').datepicker()
        .on("input change", function (e) {
            //$('.loadingBackground').show();

            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
alert(date);

});
```

This will alert the date every time the date is changed.

Or on the click event:

```
var date = $('#datePicker').datepicker('getDate');
$('#sub').on('click', function () {
    alert(date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same id in your jquery like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#sub').on('click', function () {
        var end = $('#datetimepicker').val()
        alert(end);
    });
)}
```

And you probably want to get the value after you select the date and click the #sub button.

Comment: You want to get the value after you click the #sub button? if it is put the var end declaration inside the click callback.